# How to send notification from website when client's browser is closed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I created a messenger (on web) and i want this website send people notification when someone send them a message (and receiver's browser is close).
I seen before in few website they can do that.
Thank you.
i mean First (when user come to my website), site show something like javascript `alert();` with (almost) this text :
This website want send you notification

and two buttons: allow , deny

Comment: Look into service workers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

Comment: I don't think you can do it when the browser is closed (perhaps it's different on a mobile device, though the browser would still have to be running in some limited capacity)

Comment: https://firebase.google.com